# Difficulty Implementing mousePressed and mouseReleased

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I've been trying to use mousePressed and mouseReleased but to no avail. The purpose of this program is to obtain an initial coordinate for the center of a circle from the mousepressed and to use the mousereleased to determine the radius of this circle. For some reason, I can't get the ball to repaint such that its center is the same position as the mousePressed(). I know that the first two parameters of the Ellipse2D object determine top-left corner of the ellipse, so if the radius length is subtracted from the x coordinate and the radius length is added to the y coordinate, shouldn't the ball appear at the first mouse click? I'm having difficulty understanding why it won't construct where I want it to.

Edit 1: Reformatted program for readability, made program compilable.

Here is the relevant portion of my program...

### **Main Class**

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;

 public class Main{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            CircleComponent component = new CircleComponent();
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Bouncing Ball");

            class mousePressedListener implements MouseListener
            {
            int x1, y1, x2, y2;

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { }
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            x1 = e.getX();
            y1 = e.getY();

            System.out.println(x1+ "|x1");
            System.out.println(y1+ "|y1");

            }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){   
            x2 = e.getX();
            y2 = e.getY();
            System.out.println(x2 + "|x2");
            System.out.println(y2 + "|y2");
            frame.getHeight();
            frame.getWidth();
            component.moveBall(frame.getHeight(), frame.getWidth(), x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }
        }

        class timeListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
            frame.getHeight();
            frame.getWidth();
            component.moveBall(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
            }
        }

    frame.add(component); //adds the ball to frame
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //creates square panel with specific size and the default exit

    ActionListener listener = new timeListener();
    Timer timer = new Timer(500, listener);
    timer.start();

    frame.addMouseListener(new mousePressedListener());
   }
   }
```

### **CircleComponent Class**

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.Color;


public class CircleComponent extends JComponent{

    private int x, y, a, b;
    int radius = 50;
    private Color color = Color.WHITE;
    private int dx = 1, dy = 1;//initializes the speed of the ball
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(color);
        Ellipse2D ball = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 2*radius, 2*radius);
        g2.fill(ball);
    }
    public void moveBall(int inWidth, int inHeight){
        if(x<0 || x>inWidth-65){
        dx = -dx;
        }
        if(y<0 || y>inHeight-150) {
        dy = -dy;
        }
        x = x + dx;
        y = y + dy;
        repaint();
    }
    public void moveBall(int inWidth, int inHeight, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
        double r = (double) (Math.pow((x1-x2),2) + Math.pow((y1-y2),2));
        radius = (int) Math.sqrt(r);
        System.out.println(radius+"|radius");
        if(x<0 || x>inWidth-65){
        dx = -dx;
        }
        if(y<0 || y>inHeight-150) {
        dy = -dy;
        }
        x = x1-radius;
        y = y1+radius;
        x = x + dx;
        y = y + dy;
        System.out.println(x+"X"+y+"Y");
        repaint();
     }
}
```

Comment: Swing and MouseListener tags added, so that the appropriate experts are attracted to this question.

Comment: As noted in my answer, you've posted poorly formatted code making our reading and understanding of your code difficult. I've been trying to go through it, but also find that you've posted uncompilable code, possibly from being in a hurry and being careless. Please don't do this. It's hard enough struggling to understand someone else's code, and you shouldn't make it harder still.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, I do, but seriously, you can't declare variables outside of the CircleClass class block. Again, if you're sloppy with your posted code, it makes our life difficult.

Comment: Yes, that's a glaringly obvious copy/paste error. Thanks. I'll fix it.

Comment: Thank you for fixing it. I stand by my answer. A mouse listener must be added to a component to work.

Comment: Are you saying that the frame.addMouseListener in the Main Class doesn't account for this already? @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: The CirclComponent will swallow up the mouse events (because it is on top of the frame) and will never reach the frame. Therfore add the mouselistener to the CircleComponent as @HovercraftFullOfEels states in his answere

Comment: And note that there was no code adding the MouseListener to anything in your original code!

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your more recent code.

Answer (score 1):

A MouseListener needs to be added to a viable GUI component for its magic to work, and you never seem to add your MouseListener to anything. You need to call `.addMouseListener(...)` on your CircleComponent object and pass in your created MouseListener.

As an aside, your code as formatted is very difficult to read. Please consider editing your post and fixing your indentation style so that it is uniform and consistent. I usually avoid using tabs for indenting (forum software often doesn't play well with tabs) and indent each code block 4 spaces.

---

**Edit**
Other suggestions:

- Again, add the MouseListener to the CircleComponent instance, what you name "component".
- I'd not make the MouseListener an inner class, but rather make it its own stand alone class.
- You don't need a reference to the JFrame in the MouseListener, only the CircleComponent instance, which you can get by passing in a reference into the MouseListener's constructor, or by calling `(CircleComponent) e.getSource()`
- In the MouseListener get the CircleComponent's width and height.
- You will need to call the super's method inside of your paintComponent override.
- Your calculations are off and you will need to debug these.